# Save hyperlinked files to a folder vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, hyperlink, attachment

I have a parts database and we have been using the Access 2010 attachment feature to attach PDFs to each part number. I have some working code that did what I was looking to do, which was to query a given list of parts and save just the attached PDF files to a folder. I now changed the [PDF] column to a hyperlink column, because I was worried I would eventually exceed the 3GB limit.

Is there a way I can modify this code to work with a hyperlink field instead of the attachment type field?

The ultimate goal here is to make a CD with all part documents (PDFs) for our customer.

```
Private Sub Command32_Click()
'this creates a folder for me
If Dir([filePath] & [newFolder], vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir [filePath] & [newFolder]
Else

MsgBox ("Folder:" & " " & [newFolder] & " " & "already Exists")
Exit Sub
End If

'code to loop through present list and save attached files to the new folder

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsParent As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset2

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsParent = Me.Recordset

With rsParent
.MoveFirst 'This ensures that regardless of your current record, the loop will start with the first record

Do While Not .EOF

Set rsChild = rsParent.Fields("pdf").Value

    With rsChild
    Do While Not .EOF
        If rsChild.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            rsChild.OpenRecordset
            rsChild.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile ([filePath] & [newFolder])
            Me.Refresh
            .MoveNext
     Else
        .MoveNext
     End If
    Loop
  End With

.MoveNext
Loop
End With
Exit_SaveImage:

Exit Sub
' error stuff
Err_SaveImage:
If Err = 3839 Then
    MsgBox ("All Done")
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox "There's been an error!", Err.Number, Err.DESCRIPTION
    Resume Exit_SaveImage
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the field containing your file URL is named `FileURL` , change

```
rsChild.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile ([filePath] & [newFolder])
```

to

```
Filecopy rsChild.Fields("FileURL"), [filePath] & [newFolder]
```

**Note: Instead of `Hyperlink`, define your `FileURL` field as a normal string containing the full qualified filename.**

Hope this helps

Comment: I did try what you have suggested. i replaced the line of code above and to point out the field containing the hyperlink is now called doc_attachment and is set up as a hyperlink column in the underlining table.    now when i run the code i get the error on                             'Set rsChild = rsParent.Field("Doc_Attachment").Value'                                                 object doesent support this property or method

Comment: 1) You say that your field 'doc_attachment' contains your hyperlink. Please read my boded note above. 2) You cannot define a recordset (rsChild) as an Hyperlink! Pls edit your question with your table definition.